# Querying web.config using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, config

I think the API for ASP.NET config files is way-outed. There's a new System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager class with .NET 4, but its built in the same mold as System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.

I'd rather just be able to query the model of the running configuration as an XDocument using LINQ.

Is there a way to get the model of the configuration and parse its XML using System.Linq.Xml? Can I simply open "~/Web.config" and parse its content into an XDocument--will this be accurate?

Comment: Why would you need or want to do this?

Comment: @Phill, clearly because it is "way-outed". ;)

Answer (score 3):

**No, this is not accurate.**

Configuration files work in layers, that is, you have machine.config, and *web*.config... I can even remember of more of these config files...

The classes you have mentioned can handle this layering quite transparently... that is, without requiring you to merge things manually.

You could use the config file as an Xml file, but you cannot say that you are retrieving all the configurations that apply to your application, just by reading one config file.

Comment: doesn't mean you shouldn't be able to query the merged configuration ;)

Comment: @tster: You are correct. It is possible to implement an IQueryable or some other abstraction over the current API... in my answer I mean that it is not reliable to use config files as being just simple Xml files. But making a Linq provider, or implementing Linq would be best suited to Microsoft, not one independent person... it would be an overkill... I think!

Comment: I give your answer a +1 because I agree with your comment ;)